# Showing $\Gamma\vdash A$ and $\Gamma\vdash \lnot B$ from $\Gamma\vdash\lnot (A\to B)$ using sequent calculus

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

Suppose $\Gamma\vdash\lnot (A\to B)$. How do I show that both $\Gamma\vdash A$ and $\Gamma\vdash \lnot B$ using sequent calculus inference rules?

Here is my attempt to obtain $\Gamma\vdash A$: From $\Gamma\vdash\lnot (A\to B)$, I can obtain $A\to B,\Gamma\vdash$ using $\lnot$L rule and the cut rule using process outlined [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4873769/1139213). The sequent $B\vdash B,A\to B$ is easily derivable. After applying the cut rule to both $A\vdash A,A\to B$ and $A\to B,\Gamma\vdash$, we get $\Gamma,A\vdash A$...

What are next steps should I take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From axiom $A \vdash A$ derive $A \vdash A,B$ by $(\text {Weak})$and then $\vdash A \to B,A$. Using $(\lnot \text L)$ we get: $\lnot (A \to B) \vdash A$ and we are ready for $(\text {Cut})$.

The same starting from $B,A \vdash B$ to $B \vdash A \to B$ from which $\lnot (A \to B) \vdash \lnot B$.