# Deriving $\Phi\vdash\Delta$ from $\lnot\lnot\Phi\vdash\Delta$ without cut rule?

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

I revisited the [old post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873704/double-negation-in-sequent-calculus) and I am confused with the answer. The cut elimination theorem states that for any sequent that is derived with cut rule, there exists a derivation of the same sequent without using cut rule. It seems like that the answer suggested that it is impossible to derive $\Phi\vdash\Delta$ from $\lnot\lnot\Phi\vdash\Delta$ without cut? Is it a counterexample to cut elimination theorem? If not, how do I derive $\Phi\vdash\Delta$ from $\lnot\lnot\Phi\vdash\Delta$ without cut?

Comment: No, the answer is saying that since we have cut-elimination, if we can show that $\neg \neg \Phi \vdash \Delta \implies \Phi \vdash \Delta$ using cut, then we know that it follows without cut.

Comment: IMO, the only way to prove $\lnot \lnot \Phi \vdash \Delta$ is to start from $\Phi \vdash \Delta$, **assuming that** $\Phi \in \Delta$.